# jquery hide all open divs and toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have 2 links and depending on which one they click on want to close all others and show only the information for that link.

Example:

```
<div class="shipping-container">
    <a href="#" class="ups">Show UPS info</a>
    <a href="#" class="fedex">Show Fedex info</a>
    <div class="ups info" style="display:none">the info for ups</div>
    <div class="fedex info" style="display:none">the info for fedex</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can do this with Jquery toggle for clicking one of the links and hide all others if there open. I only want to show info for one shipping method at a time. Also I would like an option for the user to click showall and all of them are displayed, if possible. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Kyle, you should not edit your question to reply to answers or comments. You can and should comment on icktoofay's answer instead.

Comment: When I try answer #2 it doesnt work when I add it into my site. It All the divs stay closed. Any ideas? I appreciate the help. Yes, it does work though on a test page. Why wouldnt it work on my live site? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Peter: Kyle doesn't have the rep yet to add comments to other's answers. He does have the rep to comment on his own question. @Kyle: I see your proposed edits to Robin's answer. Don't do that. Add a comment to your own question.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: According to the FAQ, anyone with any amount of reputation can comment on answers on their own questions. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation-abilities (see † footnote)

Comment: @Peter: Hmm. I thought otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".shipping-container a").click(function() {
    $("div.info").hide();
    $("div." + this.className).show();
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/TEdcz/)

Comment: For that to work correctly, you'd have to reorder the inner statements.

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite the selectors so only links and div's in `div.shipping-container` will be affected by this script. I would then delete my response, as I posted almost the exact same as you.

Comment: @andre - I had refined it to `.shipping-container` (without the tagName filter) about a minute before you posted the comment, but you are right, the more specific the selector, the better (in most cases).

Comment: Okay, I deleted mine. I didn't see your change before.

Comment: getting an error in firefox when trying to use this. server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".shipping-container > a.ups").click(function() {
    $(".shipping-container > .info").hide();
    $(".shipping-container > .ups.info").show();
    return false;
});
$(".shipping-container > a.fedex").click(function() {
    $(".shipping-container > .info").hide();
    $(".shipping-container > .fedex.info").show();
    return false;
});
$(".shipping-container > a.showall").click(function() {
    $(".shipping-container > .info").show();
    return false;
});
```

Or, if you wanted shiny animations (and the ability to easily add more shipping types):

```
["ups", "fedex"].forEach(function(method) {
    $(".shipping-container > a."+method).click(function() {
        $(".shipping-container > .info:not(."+method+")").slideUp("slow");
        $(".shipping-container > ."+method+".info").slideDown("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
$(".shipping-container > a.showall").click(function() {
    $(".shipping-container > .info").slideDown("slow");
    return false;
});
```

**A slightly modified example is [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/KkhjA/1/).**

Answer (score 0):

Almost same as above

```
$(".shipping-container a").click(function() {
    $("div.info").hide().filter("div." + this.className).show();
});
```

I dont know if this is more efficient than reselecting the div... it might be.

Also, if the html is the actual one, you might want to use methods like *siblings* for instance:

```
$(".shipping-container a").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("div.info").hide().filter("div." + this.className).show();
});
```

I think it's quicker.