# Simple add class to the link of toggled div

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass

My question add and amendment to a question previously asked: [jquery hide all open divs and toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910177/jquery-hide-all-open-divs-and-toggle)

The final answer does exactly what I want it to do but when I attempt to add an active class to the the link as well, the function stops running.

How would I also add and active class to the link that is specific to the div it is showing?

```
$('.stackedTabs a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div.itemContent').hide().filter('div.' + this.className).show();
    $(this).removeClass('active').filter(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to essentially create a way to toggle whether or not to have an active class. This is a way to do that.

However, this is a highly googleable question and is simple enough to find.

```
$('.stackedTabs a').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

Comment: Actually toggling a class on a single element is not the problem. Yes that is simple. But what I'm doing is using the class on the <a> and opening the div with the same class. Now when I tried to add and active class to the corresponding <a>, the function stopped working after one pass: https://jsfiddle.net/thinkbliss/nLqs8aqn/

Comment: I fixed it. Your answer did help. Thanks